# What's the battery life of the new iPad 4G with LTE disabled/enabled?

Tags: ipad, battery, lte

I saw a video about the new iPad and it showed that you could disable LTE.

[image]

Apple had to increase the battery capacity in the new iPac because upgrades like LTE and the new display draw significantly more power.

### Question

- What's the battery life of the new iPad 4G with LTE disabled/enabled?
- [Apple's product specs](http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/) are unspecific: "Up to 9 hours of surfing the web using cellular data network."

Comment: I find it suspicious they are so vague about the type of cellular data network. My guess is enabling LTE would actually bring the 9h down instead of the opposite. I think the larger battery should be attributed mostly to the retina display.

Comment: @Gerry I tend to agree with you. It would be a bummer if LTE on the iPad would not last a day.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure. But what I do know it the fact the battery in the new iPad has [70% more capacity](http://www.tuaw.com/2012/03/09/new-ipad-battery-has-70-more-capacity/) and people describe it as [massive](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2012/03/15/new-ipad-teardown-reveals-massive-battery/).

It has a massive 11,666mAh (the iPad 2 has just 6994mAH). The same battery in an iPad 2 would give...

> To put that in context, an iPad 2 with with this new battery, if such
>   a device existed, would probably last close to 17 hours on Wi-Fi.

So I'm as curious as you are about the finding of the new battery! I'm waiting for the first reviews (it shouldn't be that long anymore since the first iPad are already sold...)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the length of the battery, but I have some anecdotal evidence that may be useful.

The iPad was fully charged at 6 AM, but I didn't use it until 11. By 3 PM, after watching  two episodes of *Game of Thrones* (55 and 45 minutes long) among other things, that battery was showing 20% charge. I have push email off and no notifications, and I was on WiFi.

Comment: Is your iPad an 3G/LTE iPad or the WiFi-only model?

Answer (score 0):

The battery is great, really lasts all day long but Also takes about 6 hours to fully charge. Well we can't have everything our way. Love it tho.

Answer (score 0):

well, according to the official [Apple Website](http://www.apple.com/ipad/features/), if you scroll about halfway down the page that I gave the link to, on the right side, you should find a small paragraph, saying that the battery life of the new IPad is actually 10 hours.

Comment: Thanks for that answer! I'm aware of this. However, the problem remains that Apple's information is unclear on what is the power consumption with LTE enabled.